# Transferring question form one account to the other

Tags: support, multiple-accounts, merge-accounts

I have two accounts in maths SE. Can I transfer a question from one account to the other. If yes,how? And if I do that will be able to carry along my reputation. If that is not possible can I put one account within the other so that both accounts will have the same identity and will open with the same user id and password.

Comment: You can [merge the accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Transferring a single question from one account to another would as far as I know require manual intervention by an employee of Stack Exchange. While technically it is probably possible, it would need very extraordinary circumstances to be considered.

Comment: Hi, I see that your question has been voted down by someone. Note that the meaning of downvotes on the meta site is different from that on the main site. Here, a downvote usually means that someone does not agree with your ideas, rather than that your question is bad. Heavy downvotes are normal and more frequent than on the main site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is readily available in the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the accounts by contacting the Maths SE help center. Just go to this link -https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts